# Python Scrapy 301 redirects

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a little problem in printing the redirected urls (new URLs after 301 redirection) when scraping a given website. My idea is to only print them and not scrape them. My current piece of code is:

```
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'rust'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #if response.status == 301:
        print response.url
```

However, this does not print the redirected urls. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To parse any responses that are not 200 you'd need to do one of these things:

#### Project-wide

You can set setting `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [301,302,...]` in `settings.py` file. Or if you want to enable it for all codes you can set `HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL = True` instead.

#### Spider-wide

Add `handle_httpstatus_list` parameter to your spider. In your case something like:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    # or 
    handle_httpstatus_all = True
```

#### Request-wide

You can set these `meta` keys in your requests `handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302,...]` or `handle_httpstatus_all = True` for all:

```
scrapy.request('http://url.com', meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]})
```

To learn more see [HttpErrorMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror)

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work. Even after setting this in the spider, I get 3 urls which are not getting downloaded. These are http to https redirects apparently and I can get them from the browser. But scrapy stats still show me `downloader/response_status_count/301': 3`. I am wondering if this solution really works

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing anything? I've reworked the answer to include more cases. But generally it should work, if it doesn't you should open up a new issue with your source code.

Comment: FYI for other users, a 301 redirect handled means that scrapy won't follow the redirect no matter what you do. You will need to introduce some logic  in your parse method to handle the 301,302 codes. The other codes like 404 or 500 should work out of the box.