# How to callback on 301 redirect without crawling in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I am scraping a search result page where in some cases a 301 redirect will be triggered. In that case I do not want to crawl that page, but I need to call a different callback function, passing the redirect URL string to it.

I belive it should be possible to do it along the rules, but could not figure out how to:

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(              
                    allow=['^https://www\.testrule*$'],                               
                ), 
                follow=False,
                callback= 'parse_item'
            ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parsing %s', response.url)
        print(response.status)
        print(response.headers[b'Location'])
```

The logfile only shows:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET https:...
```

But the parsind info never gets printed, indicating never entering the function.

How can I

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658247/python-scrapy-301-redirects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Scrapy 301 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658247/python-scrapy-301-redirects)

Comment: I believe this is different. I am scraping a given list of searches defined in start_URL and have a regex in the rules preventing any other URL from scraping and following. Now the response in that case is 301, the log tells me "crawled". I don't want it to crawl, but I need to parse the response URL string which already contains the information I need to know. I did not find an anwer that helps solving this so far on SO. @gangabass

Comment: By default, Scrapy will follow redirect. If you don't need that behavior you need to use above settings and process response manually in your code (extract redirect URL etc).

Comment: The later one is exactly the problem I am facing. How to process the response? Where can I call a callback method and passt the response url to process it?

Comment: Same Scrapy request: `scrapy.Request(url=your_url, callback=self.your_callback)`. But inside your callback you can check response status code and catch redirect.

Comment: OK, I underatand. Somehow my call function never get called on 301. I get in logs: "DEBUG: Crawled (301)...". To make srcapy call the callback function also on 301 I tried:     handle_httpstatus_list = [301] inside class and also the global settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't understand why my suggestions don't work for you. This is a tested code:

```
import scrapy

class RedirectSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'redirect_spider'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/pesticidesagrochemicals/piindustries/PII',
            meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.status)
        print(response.headers[b'Location'])
        pass
```

Comment: Cool! That works. It however introduced a new problem for me. I have an array of URLs I want to scrape: start_urls = [] that was passed to the ruleset. Now I removed the ruleset to go with your example. How can I iterate through start_urls?

Comment: `for url in self.start_urls:`